# What causes the error I xform code

Tags: xforms, xpath-2.0

I receive an error running the following code:

```
<xf:output value="if(contains(instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist, ./@id), '+', '-')"/>
```

In this section: Oops, an error occured...

```
xforms-compute-exception expected "then", found "<eof>"
```

How do I fix the `if` statement?
create tree menu source.
Please let us know if you have any other source, see the tree menu will

```xml
<html
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
   <head>
      <title>Folding Menus</title>
      <xf:model id="modelID" ev:event="" functions="" schema="">
         <xf:instance id="instanceData" xmlns="">
            <group id="mainGroup">
               <group id="group1" fold="0" category="Category One">
                  <item id="item1">Enter Data</item>
                  <item id="item2">Enter Data</item>
                  <item id="item3">Enter Data</item>
                  <group id="group2" fold="0" category="Category Two">
                     <item id="item4">Enter Data</item>
                     <item id="item5">Enter Data</item>
                     <group id="group3" fold="0" category="Category Three">
                        <item id="item6">Enter Data</item>
                        <item id="item7">Enter Data</item>
                        <item id="item8">Enter Data</item>
                     </group>
                     <item id="item9">Enter Data</item>
                  </group>
               </group>
            </group>
         </xf:instance>
         <xf:instance id="foldedNodes" xmlns="">
            <foldednodes>
               <nodelist />
            </foldednodes>
         </xf:instance>

         <xf:bind nodeset="descendant::*"
            relevant="not(contains(instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist, current()/parent::*/@id))"
          />
      </xf:model>

      <style type="text/css">
         @namespace xhtml url("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
         @namespace xf url("http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms");
         xf|*:disabled {
         display: none;
         }
      </style>

   </head>

   <body>

      <div class="header">Folding Test</div>

      <xf:group id="mainGroup">
         <xf:output ref="instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist">
            <xf:label>ID List</xf:label>
         </xf:output>
         <xf:repeat nodeset="instance('instanceData')/descendant::group" id="repeatGroup">
            <xf:output class="outputInline"
               value="concat(substring('&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;',1,3 * count(current()/ancestor::*)), '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;')" />
            <xf:trigger>
               <xf:label>
                  <xf:output
                     value="if(contains(instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist, ./@id), '+', '-')"
                   />
               </xf:label>
               <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                  <xf:setvalue ref="instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist"
                     value="if(contains(instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist, instance('instanceData')/descendant::group[position()=index('repeatGroup')]/@id), concat(substring-before(instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist, instance('instanceData')/descendant::group[position()=index('repeatGroup')]/@id), substring-after(instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist, instance('instanceData')/descendant::group[position()=index('repeatGroup')]/@id)), concat(instance('foldedNodes')/nodelist, instance('instanceData')/descendant::group[position()=index('repeatGroup')]/@id))"
                   />
               </xf:action>
            </xf:trigger>
            <xf:output class="outputInline" ref="./@category" />
            <xf:repeat nodeset="./item" id="repeatItem">
               <xf:output class="outputInline"
                  value="concat(substring('&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;',1,3 * count(current()/ancestor::*)), '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;')" />
               <xf:output class="outputInline" ref="./@id">
                  <xf:label>id: </xf:label>
               </xf:output>
               <xf:input class="inputInline" ref=".[name() = 'item' or name() = 'file']">
                  <xf:label>data: </xf:label>
               </xf:input>
            </xf:repeat>
         </xf:repeat>
      </xf:group>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of XPath 2.0, "if" as a function has been deprecated. You should try with "choose" instead.

-Alain